# Apache Camel: How to properly nest a function?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

In Camel's [Simple documentation](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) they say :

> From Camel 2.9 onwards you can nest functions, such as shown below:
>
> ```
> <setHeader headerName="myHeader">
>   <simple>${properties:${header.someKey}}</simple>
> </setHeader>
> ```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<simple>${property.${property.prefix}variableName}</simple>
```

I am trying to access the exchange property whose name is:

```
exchange.getProperty("prefix", String.class) + "variableName"
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: ${ cannot accept or at location 22
${property.${property.prefix}variableName}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Camel version **2.13.0**.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the following code works fine with Camel `2.13.0`:

```
from("...")
    .setProperty("prefix", constant("pre-"))
    .setProperty("pre-variable", constant("value"))
    .setHeader("myHeader", simple("${property.${property.prefix}variable}"))
```

You may have special character in the `prefix` property that prevents proper resolution.

Comment: My prefix contains only letters and underscores. But you set the property on the result of from("...") while I set it on the exchange.

Comment: Hum, setting it on the result of `from(...)` is equivalent to setting on the exchange. Creating a processor that sets the property on the exchange works similarly. Maybe you could share a bit more context about your Camel route to help identifying what's the difference.